# "The connection to the daemaon was lost" when updating Ubuntu

Tags: updates

I recently did my first Ubuntu update. One of the items posted this:

> The connection to the daemaon was lost.  Most likely the daemon crashed.

When I clicked the *details* icon, this message came up:

> It seems that the daemon died.

Other than that it appears that all the updates were processed.

What does all this mean and is there any reason to be concerned or fear that a virus is on my PC? When my AV scans does it include a scan of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's never any reason to be worried about viruses on Ubuntu as long as you keep it upgraded. If there was, then an anti-virus solution would be included by default.

A daemon is just a program that runs in the background. Something happened to a process the update manager uses to install updates. It's nothing to worry about at all. Specially if everything works. If it doesn't, just run the update-manager again.

Answer (score 0):

The first time I got this message was today, doing the update that includes mods to OpenSSL.

I cannot agree that there is no danger of viruses in Ubuntu. Less than windows? yes.

Also, as the "Heartbleed" bug shows, the world's web servers are vulnerable too.